# Optimizing a function with 2 variables with matrix form

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization

Someone else asked a question, I've been thought a lot, but still have no ideas. Could someone give me some advice about question below?
$$
\min_{X,Z\in S^{++}}||-nZ+XA+B||_F^2
$$
$$
s.t \quad XZ-I=0, ZX-I=0
$$
where,$X,Z$ are variables. $S^{++}$ means positive definite matrix, and $A$ is a diagonal matrix, $B$ is a symmetric matrix, $n>0$ is a constant number.

Comment: No solution exists. If $X$ and $Z$ are positive definite, $XZ+I$ cannot be zero.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks a lot, but I wonder how many time do you spend on this website a day?

Comment: sorry, I have a mistake. I've been corrected it!

Comment: So, $Z=X^{-1}$. What a strange way to put it. What is $n$? Is $X$ $n\times n$? Is it positive?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, I think it will be easier to solve with the auxiliary variable $Z$. It will be ok if you can solve this problem:$$
\min_{X\in S^{++}}||-nX^{-1}+XA+B||_F^2
$$